# Configure Apache Ignite Cluster on multiple nodes

Tags: ignite

I want to setup Ignite cluster on 3 nodes on different IPs. I am following  [the official guide](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-multicast-ip-finder)and using this configuration. I have listed the node IPs in multicastGroup property - unfortunately this does not work, throwing following exception

```
[09:08:40,852][SEVERE][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to register local node address in IP finder on start (retrying every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
    class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Unknown multicast group: 10.10.17.1,10.10.17.2,10.10.17.3
```

This is my configuration file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<!--
    Alter configuration below as needed.
-->
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
             <property name="ipFinder">
                 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                     <property name="multicastGroup" value="10.10.17.1,10.10.17.2,10.10.17.3"/>
                 </bean>
             </property>
         </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

How to setup correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've configured node IPs in the wrong place. Please configure them as follow:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
   <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
         <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
             <property name="addresses">
               <list>
      <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                <value>10.10.17.1:47500..47509</value>
                <value>10.10.17.2:47500..47509</value>
                <value>10.10.17.3:47500..47509</value>
               </list>
             </property>
            </bean>
         </property>
     </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

We are using the above configuration. Unfortunately always the node mentioned on top ( here 10.10.17.1:47500..47509) is getting discovered but the other two nodes remain undiscovered.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've added an answer which should've been a question really. I suggest you remove this answer and ask a new question, mentioning all of the details: your configuration, how you run the cluster, the behavior you see, logs, and the steps you've already taken to find a solution.